# Validity VFS491 Fingerprint Scanner issue on ProBook 4540s running Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, fingerprint-reader

I am using ubuntu 18.04 on HP ProBook 4540s.
Following is the output of `lsusb` :

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0cf3:311d Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f2:b370 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:003d Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS491
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I can't configure the fingerprint scanner (validity VFS491, as shown in the list above). I have tried fprintd, fingerprint etc available on help forums and on hp website. Nothing seems to be working. Any help?

Comment: This guide works for me
i'm on ProBook 4430s
https://github.com/PetreBoboc/vfs495/blob/master/vfs495_ubuntu_18.04.md

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have installed the driver from HP website

Simply just search the Serial number of the product you can get that with:

```
dmidecode -s system-serial-number
```

if the driver is installed try installing `libfprint`